# Limit the parallelisation of Upstart?

Tags: configuration, startup, upstart

If I understand right, Upstart runs all tasks that are ready to run in parallel.

However, is there a way to limit the amount of parallelisation? That is, the number of parallel tasks that are run should be capped by some constant.

For example, `make` allows you to run all tasks in parallel with the `-j` option. If you want to restrict the amount of parallel jobs, you can pass a number to it. Thus, `-j 2` means run jobs in parallel but not more than two at a time.

I am looking for the equivalent setting in upstart.

**Edit**
I just realized that my question is silly. If the jobs are daemons that never stop, then there is no way for Upstart to decide that they are done.
Instead, what I need is a way to limit by disk i/o. That is, when disk i/o is high, upstart shouldn't spawn new jobs. It should only spawn after disk activity cools down.

Comment: @RamchandraApte Not sure what you mean. I don't know an answer yet.

Comment: well, there are many init scripts which are run by upstart and which are parallelism. Your question is valid, not silly. Also daemons typically are in disk sleep and consume almost 0% CPU, so upstart can spawn tens of daemons (actually a standard Linux system has many daemons running). so actually upstart probably ignores daemons in its "parallelism count".

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at upstarts documentation? I strongly suggest to you to skim through it. It can be found [here.](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

One simple way could be to delay some between each start or use a post-start script to delay until your service is up before you start next instance? Have a look at some of the examples to get some ideas how to handle it. Eg. `6.22`  `6.14.2` `++` http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ You can also extend that script to suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, I did skim through the cookbook. What I need is a system-wide setting which throttles the parallel execution of all tasks. Right now, my hard disk is saturated during startup, which I believe is due to a large number of tasks getting spawned simultaneously.

Comment: @HRJ It's probably so because of ureadahead, which caches the hard disk into memory.